# Have two classes share an actor

Tags: swift, concurrency

I currently have a simple `actor Model {}` that's the single source of truth for my application.

I want to define a kind of 'view' on this model (`FlatModel`) that should listen for events from the `Model` and update its corresponding state. The events from the `Model` are the only source for modification of this `FlatModel`, but as there are concurrent reads on this `FlatModel` it also needs an isolated context. There is no explicit need for the `Modal` and `FlatModel` to be isolated from each other.

I tried various ways to get this to work but none them want to compile. The most promising tries:

**Two actors:**

```
actor Model {}
actor FlatModel {
    init(model: Model) {
        model.somePublisher.sink {
            self.doSomething() //<- Actor 'self' can only be captured from an async initializer
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {}
}

final class Document: NSDocument {
    let model = Model()
    lazy var flatModel: FlatModel(model: model)
}
```

Making the `init()` async as suggested by the compiler message prevents me from instantiating the `FlatModel` from `Document`'s `init()`.

**Global Actor:**

```
@globalActor
struct ModelActor {
    actor ActorType { }
    static let shared: ActorType = ActorType()
}

@ModelActor
final class Model {}

@ModelActor
final class FlatModel {
    init(model: Model) {
        model.somePublisher.sink {
            self.doSomething()
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {}
}

final class Document: NSDocument {
    let model = Model() //<- Call to global actor 'ModelActor'-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous main actor-isolated context
//    lazy var flatModel: FlatModel(model: model)
}
```

I would rather not give `Model` any knowledge about `FlatMmodel` to keep good code separation and testability.

Is there a way to make such a setup work?

Comment: What about bringing `Document` class into `ModelActor` scope? Does that solve your issue?

Comment: (NS)Document is a main actor thing due to AppKit requirements.